# visualización de texto en Pygame y el error Text has zero width

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, io, width

EL caso es el siguiente, estoy haciendo un juego de navecitas usando Pygame no obstante no use la fuente que viene esta biblioteca si no advanced_pixel_lcd-7.ttf (fuente externa), el caso es que al usarlo los problemas se presentaron, cuando quise hacer el ejecutable del código al usar una fuente externa use la biblioteca io para convertir la fuente mencionada en binario para que no haya problemas al convertirlo en un .exe pero ya no se ejecuta con perfección, la cuestión es que al quitar las funciones afectada corre con normalidad, el error es **Text has zero width**.

```
#fuente bytes
def fuente_bytes(fuente):
    with open(fuente, "rb") as f:                   #abre el archivo en binario
        bytes_ttf = f.read()                        #lee el archivo binario y lo convierte en una variable
    return io.BytesIO(bytes_ttf)                    #Devuelve la fuente para ser guardada en una varible

#puntaje y otras cosas
puntaje = 0
fuente_en_bytes = fuente_bytes("advanced_pixel_lcd-7.ttf")  #fuente usada para mostrar info
fuente = pygame.font.Font(fuente_en_bytes, 20)
texto_x = 10
texto_y = 10

#texto final
fuente_final = pygame.font.Font(fuente_en_bytes,20)         #fuente usada para mostrar info

#funcion texto final
def fuente_f():
    mi_fuente_final = fuente_final.render("Juego terminado",True ,(255,255,255))    #funcion para mostrar game over
    pantalla.blit(mi_fuente_final,(240, 300))


#funcion puntaje
def mostrar_puntaje(x, y):
    texto = fuente.render(f"Puntaje: {puntaje}",True,(255, 255, 255))   #funcion para mostrar puntaje
    pantalla.blit(texto, (x, y))
```

He intentado varias cosas, sí puntaje es vacío o menor que 1 no se ejecute la función, pero al realizar una muerte vuelve el error y lo mismo ocurre cuando pierde aun cuando ya hay un valor predefinido ¿cómo puedo solucionar este inconveniente?

Comment: Yo creo que el error debe referirse a que el texto no ocupa espacio alguno, y no al número de caracteres. Seguro que es necesario usar io para que funcione al convertirse en exe? Probaste cargar la fuente de forma "normal" (Font("tufuente ttf"))? Si haciendo esto ultimo sigue la falla, es posible que el problema sea que la fuente no es valida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que muestras es secundario a otro, el verdadero problema es que estas intentando leer del objeto `io.BytesIO` asignado a  `fuente_en_bytes` dos veces seguidas:

En la linea:

```
fuente_en_bytes = fuente_bytes("advanced_pixel_lcd-7.ttf")
```

asigna a `fuente_en_bytes` la salida de la función `fuente_bytes`, que es un objeto `io.BytesIO`:

A continuación le pasas a `pygame.font.Font` el objeto *file* en:

```
fuente = pygame.font.Font(fuente_en_bytes, 20)
```

el tema esta que `io.BytesIO` es un *file-like object* y  como cualquier file stream, tiene una posición, donde tienen lugar todas las operaciones de lectura-escritura. Como `pygame.font.Font` acaba de leer datos de él, la posición está al final, por lo que al hacer de nuevo:

```
fuente_final = pygame.font.Font(fuente_en_bytes,20)
```

`pygame.font.Font` no tiene nada que leer.

No tiene sentido que crees `fuente` y `fuente_final` siendo ambas la misma fuente, puedes usar tu variable `fuente` en ambas funciones. Pero si necesitas hacer esto, debes pesarle a cada método un nuevo objeto `file` cada vez:

```
fuente_a = pygame.font.Font(fuente_bytes("advanced_pixel_lcd-7.ttf"), 20)
fuente_b = pygame.font.Font(fuente_bytes("advanced_pixel_lcd-7.ttf"), 17)
```

o posicionar de nuevo el cursor al inicio del fichero antes de cada nueva lectura:

```
fuente_en_bytes = fuente_bytes("advanced_pixel_lcd-7.ttf")
fuente_a = pygame.font.Font(fuente_en_bytes, 20)
fuente_en_bytes.seek(0)  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
fuente_b = pygame.font.Font(fuente_en_bytes, 17)
```

Por otro lado, no hay diferencia entre usar `io.BytesIO` como lo usas y simplemente hacer:

```
fuente = pygame.font.Font("advanced_pixel_lcd-7.ttf", 20)
```

`io.BytesIO` seria de ayuda, por ejemplo, si guardaras tu fuente como un literal de bytes en el código.

Por cierto, te recomiendo usar `pygame.freetype` en vez de `pygame.font`, por ejemplo:

```
fuente = pygame.freetype.Font("advanced_pixel_lcd-7.ttf", 20)

def fuente_f():
    fuente.render_to(pantalla, (240, 300), "Juego terminado", (255, 255, 255))

def mostrar_puntaje(x, y):
    fuente.render_to(pantalla, (x, y), f"Puntaje: {puntaje}", (255, 255, 255))
```